# Email-link-auth not working: Firebase Auth always returns false for `isSignIn(withEmailLink:)`

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm attempting to follow the instructions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/email-link-auth
... and here (for the dynamic links part): https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive
... to have my iOS app tell Firebase to send an email with a link, which when the user opens on their device, causes my app to have an authenticated `User` object.

```
@objc func handleFirebaseDynamicLink(_ link: DynamicLink) {
    guard let link = link.url?.absoluteString else {
        WLog("FirebaseProvider handleFirebaseDynamicLink: WARNING, link had no url")
        return
    }
    guard let email = self.emailAddressLastEntered, Auth.auth().isSignIn(withEmailLink: link) else {
        WLog("FirebaseProvider handleFirebaseDynamicLink: WARNING, not a signInWithEmailLink or no emailAddress?")
        return
    }
```

**ISSUE**: For some reason, `Auth.auth().isSignIn...` is returning false, even though the link it is given appears to be correct:

`(lldb) po link
"https://<redacted>.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?apiKey=<redacted>&mode=signIn&oobCode=123459g71QBFRozWp4fvi-izDstx9BE2o3zhPc_jZQAAAFiU_tqpg&continueUrl=https://<redacted>/applinks/firebaseprovider/signin"`

If I ignore this and just call `Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, link: link)`, it crashes with an exception of trying to insert a nil value into an NSDictionary :(

Here is the code i'm calling to generate the email send:

```
        let actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings.init()
        actionCodeSettings.url = URL.init(string: "https://<redacted>/applinks/firebaseprovider/signin")
        actionCodeSettings.handleCodeInApp = true
        actionCodeSettings.setIOSBundleID(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
        Auth.auth().sendSignInLink(toEmail: emailAddress, actionCodeSettings: actionCodeSettings, completion: { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                WLog("FirebaseProvider signIn: ERROR on sendSignInLink: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                waitingForUserBlock(false)
                return
            }
            self.emailAddressLastEntered = emailAddress
            self.signedInBlock = signedInBlock
            waitingForUserBlock(true)
        })
```

... and here's the AppDelegate code that gets to the handler:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler {
        DDLogInfo(@"AppDelegate continueUserActivity: %@", userActivity.debugDescription);
        BOOL handled = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] handleUniversalLink:userActivity.webpageURL completion:^(FIRDynamicLink * _Nullable dynamicLink, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error) {
                DDLogWarn(@"AppDelegate continueUserActivity: ERROR on handleUniversalLink: %@", error.debugDescription);
                return;
            }
            [FirebaseProvider.shared handleFirebaseDynamicLink:dynamicLink];
        }];
        return handled;
    }

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id> *)options {
            FIRDynamicLink *dynamicLink = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] dynamicLinkFromCustomSchemeURL:url];
            if (dynamicLink) {
                [FirebaseProvider.shared handleFirebaseDynamicLink:dynamicLink];
                return YES;
            } else {
                DDLogWarn(@"%s, WARNING: openURL returning FALSE because i didn't know the prefix: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, url.absoluteString);
            }
        return false;
    }
```

I also made sure to re-download the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file, and I see in there that `IS_SIGNIN_ENABLED` is `YES` as i'd expect.

All help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the issue is that one should not handle the dynamicLink oneself. Ie. don't call `handleUniversalLink` just pass the entire link, dynamic or whatever, straight into `isSignIn`